# checking http request with angularjs and codeigniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

**hello** **everyone**, i'm building a web application using "angularjs" as a front-end and using "codeingniter" as a back-end, however when i request an request with angular using "$http" built in services, it returns data nicely, so my problem is that when i check if request is ajax using built in function in "codeigniter" :`$this->input->is_ajax_request()` the result will be not ajax request could any one help me to solve this problem  thanks a lot for all

Comment: Add `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header to `$http` requests to match what `is_ajax_request()` looks for as per CI docs . Can set as defaults or on per request basis or in httpInterceptor. `$http` doesn't seem to use it and there is no mandatory spec for any `HTTP_X***` series headers

Comment: thanks a a lot it helps me and solve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header to `$http` requests to match what `is_ajax_request()` looks for as per CI docs .

You can set as defaults or on per request basis or in httpInterceptor. $http doesn't seem to use it and there is no mandatory spec for any `HTTP_X***` series headers

Answer (score 0):

saw this https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65552.html

he fix this by

```
dgApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                if (config.data && typeof config.data === 'object') {
                    config.data = $.param(config.data);
                }
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

works for me tho.